# How to increase the speed of loop with help of np.where()

Tags: performance, loops, for-loop, optimization

word1='welcome to three'

word2='customer options team'

word3='hi you are chatting with'

word4='i will connect your chat'

word5='customer relations team'

word6='i will transfer you'

word7='i will escalate your chat'

word8='customer finance team'

word9='network support team'

word10='customer options'

word11='customer relations'

word12='customer finance'

word13='renewals team'

word14='three sales team'

word15='welcome to 3'

word16='three business'

word17='from three'

word18='finance team'

word19='technical team'

word20='msisdn:'

word21='visitor:'

word22='name:'

word23='vn:'

a_list=[]

u_chat = df2['Chat ID'].unique()

for i in u_chat:

l = list(df2[df2['Chat ID'] == i]['Sender'].unique())

for j in range(len(l)):

k = (i,l)

b=(df2[(df2['Chat ID'] == i) & (df2['Sender'] == l[j])][:1])

if b['Sender'].iloc[0] == 'Bot':
k[1][j] = 'Bot'

elif word1 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0] or word2 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0] or word3 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0] or word4 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0] or word5 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0] or word6 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0] or word7 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0] or word8 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0] or word9 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0] or word10 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0] or word11 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0] or word12 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0] or word13 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0] or word14 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0] or word15 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0] or word16 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0] or word17 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0] or word18 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0] or word19 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0]:

k[1][j] = 'Advisor'

elif b['Sender'].iloc[0] == 'Customer' or word20 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0] or word21 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0] or word22 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0] or word23 in b['Transcript'].iloc[0]:

k[1][j] = 'Customer'

else:

k[1][j] = 'Customer'

a_list.append(k)

How to I optimize the speed of code for loop using np.where() in my above code

Comment: Please format the code, indent it and make it reproducible. It is currently hard to understand. Besides, there is no `np.where` in the code...

Comment: Actually my question is that how I increase the speed of my for loop because above code is taken too much time so can u help me with that to increase the speed